# Allow users to add appointment to my Outlook calendar without seeing details of other appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, office365

I want to share my Outlook calendar with other users so they can add appointments (as well as edit and delete their own too). But I only want them to see that I'm "Busy" for any appointments they have not created. I thought that by setting the permissions shown in the screen shot below that this should work, but it doesn't allow the creation of new appointments. What have I not done? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Recently, I created a shared Calendar for room reservation (only difference is the Read permission is set to Full Details) and it works fine ... Did you wait a couple seconds for the synchro with the Exchange Server ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is Office 365 and I waited nearly 24 hours and no change. Don't really want to set full details. But this is what "Contributor" pretty much sets things and from what I've read this should do it.